# Número de acessos por páginas

Tags: c#, .net, iis

Olá, alguém sabe me dizer se o IIS possui algum recurso que eu possa ver quantos acessos cada página teve?

Comment: porque não usa o google analitys?

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar "Web Service/Current Connections", porém esses dados podem se apresentar incoerentes de acordo com a quantidade de acessos que você tiver.

Para mais informações confira essa resposta no serverfault: "https://serverfault.com/questions/371487/can-i-monitor-active-user-count-on-my-iis-sites"

Comment: Isso é para contagem de conexões. Existe também uma [ferramenta](http://www.appadmintools.com/products/countconnections.html), mas ela internamente usa o netstat.